# Schwarz reflection principle and even extension of harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $B \subset \mathbb R^2$ be the unit ball centered at origin and set $B^{\pm} := B \cap \{\pm y>0\}$ and $B^0 := B \cap \{y=0\}$.
Let $u = u(x,y)$ be a continuous function on $B^+ \cup B^0$ and harmonic in $B^+$.

The Schwarz reflection principle for harmonic functions asserts that if $u \equiv 0$ on $B^0$, then $u$ can be extended to a harmonic function on $B^-$ by the "odd extension", namely,
$$v(x,y) := \begin{cases} u(x,y), & y \geq 0 \\ -u(x,-y), & y < 0 \end{cases}$$
is harmonic on the whole $B$.

On the other hand, can we extension $u$ to whole $B$ by "even extension", namely,
$$w(x,y) := \begin{cases} u(x,y), & y \geq 0 \\ u(x,-y), & y<0 \end{cases}.$$

It is clear that if such extension is valid, we need $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,0) = 0$ since $w$ is twice differentiable.

My question: Can we extend $u$ on $B^+ \cup B^0$ harmonically on $B^-$ by even extension provided $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,0) = 0$ for all $-1 <x< 1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The “even extension” $w$ is harmonic in $B$ only if $u$ is identically zero.

A harmonic extension of $u$ from $B^+$ to $B$ is *unique* (because of the [Identity principle for harmonic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3319637/42969)).

So if both $v$ and $w$ are harmonic extensions of $u$ then necessarily $v=w$, and that is only possible if $u$ is identically zero.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question. Oh, in two dimensional case, it's going to work. I have one more question: Can we extend the identity theorem for harmonic functions in general dimension?

Comment: @naba: I am pretty sure that you can, and the proof should be essentially the same as in two dimensions (the set of all points which have a neighborhood on which $u$ is zero is both open and closed). But I do not have a reference right now.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I understood the contents roughly, and I noticed that in n dimensional case, the identity theorem is valid. Roughly speaking, since harmonic function is analytic, we can apply the same proof in the two dimensional case to in that case.

Comment: Sorry, Martin... I've only recently started using stackchange, so I'm still getting used to it... Sorry for not replying to your comment...

Comment: Thank you Martin! I find the accepting mark and do accept your answer.